# Generating a 10 volt rail from a High Voltage Supply with unknown Ground Potential

Tags: voltage-divider, dc-dc-converter

I have a sticky situation where my power supply is coming from a charged capacitor with 200 volts across it. Because of the way it was charged, I can't guarantee that the negative side of the cap is at "ground" potential.  All I can depend on is that there is a 200 volt difference.  It could be that one side of the cap is 10 volts and the other side is -190volts.  As a result of this, I'm nervous about trying to mix other control circuitry that uses a different ground potential, so what I want to do is simply use the 200 volt circuit to run the control circuitry.

From what I know all I have to do is use a voltage divider to generate a third voltage leg that has the 10 volt difference I want for my control circuitry.  Then I should be able to run IC chips (like NE555) and mosfet gates off the 10 volt difference without any problems.  It also shouldn't matter whether I make the 10 volt difference relative to the low side or the high side.

Is all my understanding correct?  Are there any problem areas I could run into when trying to divide high voltages to much lower voltages?  What if I had an even higher voltage supply such as 1000 volt?  Can I still divide it like this to run ICs and mosfets?

Here's a pic to help illustrate:
[image]

Comment: How much current do you need, at 10V?

Comment: 200 milliAmps would suffice.

Comment: Either your runtime will be very short at 200ma or you will have a very large capacitor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To supply \$200mA\$ at \$10V\$ from \$200V\$, there must necessarily be \$200mA\$ at \$190V\$ somewhere else, if you are converting the voltage by any linear method (like a voltage divider).

$$ 200mA \cdot 190V = 38W $$

That's a big resistor, transistor, or something, with a big heatsink. Not at all hard, but quite big, and warm.

Probably, you will want a non-linear voltage converter, like a [buck converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter). This will be much more efficient, and won't need to be big with a large heatsink.

If your control circuitry, and everything connected to it, is connected to only your \$10V\$ output, then it doesn't matter if that \$10V\$ is \$200V - 190V\$ relative to ground, or \$5V - -5V \$ relative to ground. After all, "ground" is just where you stick the "ground" symbol in the schematic, and the electrons can't see that.

But, if you are already using a buck converter, you could get one with an isolated output. Typically, these will use a transformer to couple the power from the input to the output, and the feedback will be done through an optoisolator. Thus, the output of the buck converter is *floating*, meaning, it has no reference to anything on the input side. You could then, if you wanted, connect your control circuit's ground to some other ground, and not be worried in a voltage difference between these grounds making some large current flow and making smoke.

Even if you don't connect it to something else, that floating output has the nice feature that when someone touches it, maybe accidentally, and that someone also happens to be touching some other potential (say, the Earth, which is connected to a lot of stuff), the output voltage will "float" to their potential, and then there won't be any difference, and they won't be shocked.

It's quite likely that any 200V to 10V buck converter you find will be isolated, for safety. So, perhaps by happy accident, you don't have to do anything special to solve both your problems.

Answer (score 1):

200 V/1050 ohm = 0.19 A

190 V x 0.19 A = 36 W. That's a pretty big resistor.

Yes, you can use either the high or the low side.

TI has a power selector that gives various possibilities. With your parameters the choices are from the UCC28701-03 parts as shown [here](http://webench.ti.com/webench5/power/webench5.cgi?lang_chosen=en_US&VinMin=200&VinMax=200&O1V=10&O1I=0.2&op_TA=30).

Comment: Well is there a better (and still relatively simple) way to do it that doesn't require a monster resistor?

Answer (score 1):

A switching power supply is what I would use and luckily there are off-the-shelf solutions that are relatively cheap. A bog-standard wall-wart will convert 90V-260V ac to (say) 12V. The output will be isolated and therefore you can ground it locally or leave it floating. I would choose one that says it can handle DC inputs (as far as I'm aware most of them do) and I would choose one which is a two pin device i.e. doesn't rely on an earth pin for safety.

How does this help? Most wall-warts initially convert the ac to dc then do the switching via a small transformer down to 12V. The initial dc they convert to is in the range 120V to 370V so 200Vdc input is ideal.

You need 10V and this is rarer than 12V so you have the options of: -

- Finding one
- Using two wall-warts with 5v outputs wired in series
- Using a linear regulator like a 7810 after the 12V output.

Option 1 - can you find one?

Option 2 is my favourite because 5V devices are plenty and having two with outs in series gives you a +5V, 0V and -5V supply.

Option 3 - nice clean output but "like a 7810" realistically means a LDO regulator but if you are into doing circuits this should be no-problem.

Comment: Most wall-warts handle DC input?  You're kidding.  This is news to me.  If that would work, that's a perfect solution.  But I thought most wall-warts have a step-down transformer as their first stage device?  Weird.  I'm going to take a look at a few.

Comment: Amazing. It's written about on the wikipedia page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_adapter

Comment: @Jim - I didn't see it written on that page but if it is a switcher (and not a big power job) then almost certainly will rectify the incoming AC therefore a DC feed is not a problem BUT go for types that are earth-free on the power pins.

Comment: 10V output wall warts are common on some DSL modems, so they won't be impossible to find.